# Stop a background worker

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a STOP button to my program to, stop a background worker. I have had no luck doing it with the following.

This is my button event

```
  Private Sub GOButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GOButton.Click
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            PullIPs()

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The PullIPs sub does alot of stuff, and at the end, starts the backgroundworker

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Backgroundworker1 kicks off another sub, like so

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50)
        PingAll()
End Sub
```

So, after that maze, I would like a way to stop the backgroundworker mid 'PingAll()'.

Lastly,

```
    Private Sub StopButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
End Sub
```

Note: SupportCancelation IS enabled. I have also looked all over the place, and it looks like I am doing it, how it should work...

Comment: It is up to you to check whether `myBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` in the BGW's DoWork handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have looked all over the place except for the one obvious place that you should have looked first, i.e. the Help documentation.  The doco for the `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync` method has this to say:

> CancelAsync submits a request to terminate the pending background
>   operation and sets the CancellationPending property to true.
>
> When you call CancelAsync, your worker method has an opportunity to
>   stop its execution and exit. The worker code should periodically check
>   the CancellationPending property to see if it has been set to true.

Where in your code are you doing as that instructs?  Nowhere, so you're obviously not doing it how it should work.

Calling `CancelAsync` only requests a cancellation.  It's still up to you to add code to your `DoWork` event handler to test whether a cancellation has been requested and stop doing the work if it has.  The `DoWork` event handler can do anything at all so calling `CancelAsync` is not going to simply abort that on the spot without any consideration for what state the app is in and whether any cleanup may be required.

You know what work is being done so it's up to you write the code such that that work can be cancelled part way through.  As it is, all you're doing is a single call to `PingAll` so there is no way to cancel it.  You need to restructure that code, e.g. turn it into a loop that does one ping per iteration and then you can cancel between iterations if required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Could I put the CancellationPending in the PingAll event?

Comment: `PingAll` is a method, not an event.  People get confused between events and event handlers.  Events get raised by an object and then event handlers are methods that get invoked when that event is raised.  `DoWork` is the event that your `BackgroundWorker` raises and `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` is your form's method that gets executed in response.

Comment: `CancellationPending` is a member of the `e` parameter of your `DoWork` event handler.  In order to be able to test its `CancellationPending` property in your `PingAll` method, you must have a reference to that object in your `PingAll` method, which would mean adding a parameter to your `PingAll` method and then passing `e` as an argument when you call it.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks so much.